# How to detect if the url sent to SafariViewController gives error 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is there any way to detect if the url sent to SafariViewController gives error 404 (page not found) and then submit to another default url or even dismiss the SafariViewController?
I'm using this way right now, objetive-c please.

```
SFSafariViewController * sfSafariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url entersReaderIfAvailable:NO];

sfSafariVC.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:sfSafariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement "safariViewController: didCompleteInitialLoad:" in SFSafariViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the delegate returns YES in this case: http://openradar.appspot.com/33400536